# Select max on 2 following columns mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a table like

```
date(int), time(int), code(int), title(varchar)
```

I should select the last row for a specific code, then the row with max time in the max date. Table is VERY big, and I should use less resource as possbile in the query

table

```
date     time code title
20161110 1045 5522 plant1
20161110 1045 5522 plant1
20161110 1100 5522 plant1
20161111 1030 5522 plant1
20161111 1045 5522 plant1
```

I expect to obtain one row

```
20161111 1045 5522 plant1
```

and that's my crappy sql

```
select * 
from ep_ft_consumptions_experimental as cons 
    (inner join (select max(date) as md 
                 from ep_ft_consumptions_experimental 
                 where plant_code=5522 
                   and d1=1
                ) dr 
        on cons.date = dr.md) 
    (inner join (select max(time) as mt 
                 from ep_ft_consumptions_experimental
                ) tr 
        on cons.time = tr.time
```

Comment: Any tries before dumping your homework here?

Comment: Why date and time separate? why not a timestamp? You're shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: Add sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text. Also show us your current query attempt, and describe what's wrong with it. Any primary key, or indexes?

Comment: timestamp would be a good idea, but i'm extending a pre-existent project

Comment: Union 2 queries ORDER BY date DESC,time DESC LIMIT 1 one of them with a WHERE for code

Comment: @Mihai thank you, how about performances on 2 nested ORDER BY on a big table?

Comment: It will be sht,use a composed index on date,time.It also depends on data distribution.It will take a while to create an index on a large table.

Comment: date tima and code are already keys

Comment: "but i'm extending a pre-existent project" If I had a nickel...

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple. Use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT 1`:

```
select cons.* 
from ep_ft_consumptions_experimental as cons 
where cons.code = 5522
order by cons.date desc, cons.time desc
limit 1 ;
```

As for efficiency, you only need to add a composite index on `(code, date, time)` if you haven't one already.

Comment: Even better is this composite index:  `INDEX(code, date, time)`.